# EXCEL Formula for Counting the cells that have dates

Tags: excel, countif

I want to count this thing. Dates are in Single Column and i want to count the Cells which falls in a Given Date Range. Sudo will be like this 
CountIfs G3:G389, Date Range 01-02-2014 to 06-02-2014 , And Count the Cells that falls in this range. I can Count them with Applying Filter. but i want to apply formula so it will be easy
See if you can Help

```
╔════════════╗
║     G3     ║
╠════════════╣
║ 02-02-2014 ║
║ 05-02-2014 ║
║ 03-02-2014 ║
║ 04-02-2013 ║
╚════════════╝
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe this function would do the trick (assumed that the date format in your example is dd-mm-yyyy):

```
=COUNTIFS(G3:G389,">=" & DATE(2014,2,1),G3:G389,"<=" & DATE(2014,2,6))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to this problem :

```
CountIfs(G3:G1400,">=02-01-2014",G3:G1400"<=08-02-2014")
```